# How to omit columns containing only NAs in a matrix?

Tags: r

I have a matrix which have many columns in which all the values are `NA`. 
So I want to omit all the columns which are entirely `NA`. So how can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

I assume you only wish to omit columns where all observations are `NA`; your question is somewhat ambiguous.

This code omits columns that are entirely `NA`, for a matrix, `x`, returning only the columns with at least one non-`NA` value:

```
x[,apply(!is.na(x),2,any)]
```

Comment: It will be slightly more memory efficient to do `x[,apply(x,2,function(xx) !any(is.na(xx)))]`, as this will not create  `is.na(x)`, just a vector of `length(ncol(x))`

Comment: @mnel Yes, if the matrix is big, my code above will be inefficient.

Answer (score 2):

```
mtx[ , -which( colSums(is.na(mtx)) == nrow(mtx) ) ]
```

If you wanted to exclude the columns that had more than 50% NA entries then:

```
mtx[ , -which( colSums(is.na(mtx)) > nrow(mtx)/2 ) ]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function "na.omit()" to remove rows which contain NA observations. This function removes rows and will return a data frame without NA's.

If you wish to drop columns where every observation contains an NA...

I'm not sure of a built-in R function to do this. However, we may consider some kind of user defined process which drops columns with the most NA's...

```
### Assume 'df' is your data frame with observational data:

### Apply a function to check whether each observation contains an NA
count <- sapply(df, is.na)
### Within each column, ask for the number of missing observations
count <- colSums(count)
### Ask R which columns have the most missing observations
index <- which.max(count)
### Subset 'df' to exclude columns with the most NA's
df <- df[, -index]
```

Comment: This answer appears assume that `df` is a `data.frame`. The question is about a `matrix`. The `sapply` approach is useful for data.frames and lists, but not for matrices.